# Is the on-screen version of Annville, Texas faithful to the comic?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, preacher, preacher-2016

I haven't read more than a couple of "Preacher" comics, but I'm currently about halfway through Season 1 of the tv show. I can't help but notice that the town of Annville is rife with Hollywood stereotypes of Southern people. So far, the show has included:

- a racist, sexist Sheriff who ignores a report of possible spousal abuse
- townspeople who enjoy beating up their new politically correct mascot
- numerous hypocrites in Custer's congregation, including a child molester, said Sheriff, and a couple who are into S&M
- a local "cattle baron" who rules his company with an iron fist
- the employees of said cattle baron, who literally get away with murder
- a whorehouse

I often see these stereotypes in films and on TV, and as someone who grew up in Texas, I can assure you that they're no more the norm *there* than they are anywhere else.

**Is the on-screen version of Annville, Texas faithful to the Preacher comics, or is this just Hollywood stereotyping of small Texas (or even just Southern in general) towns?**

---

**Note:** I realize that the nature of this topic could easily devolve into a political discussion, so in advance, let's try to keep comments and answers on-topic.

Comment: You might want to use the [adaptation-comparison] tag, though the two are too similar at times.

Comment: Thanks! I have both on there now. If needed, someone can edit as necessary

Comment: My limited understanding  of the comics is that they begin AFTER the Preacher has left town. Season one of the TV series was non-canon. But I could be misremembering.

Comment: @Paulie_D Annville was in flashback. Show is a show; only a loose adaptation, much different from original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the characters of Annville in the TV series are actually taken from later on in the Comics, and in some cases are in fact toned down a bit.

For instance in the comics the Cattle Barons assistant is a hardcore Dominatrix who ends up submitting to Custer. That same cattle baron is found making love to a mannequin made of meat, throughout the books many characters throughout the world are depicted as being deviant, twisted, perverted and with no morales and in regards to Southern characters they are depicted as all the above and more.